# ES6 errors in CodeSanbox are not showed

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

i want check some Js code in codesandbox vanilaJs template:

```
console.log(x);
let x = 5; 

expect - Reference Error
actual - undefined (same with const)
```

or

```
let x = 5
(function(){
   console.log(x);
    let x = 6;
})();

expect - Reference Error
actual - undefined
```

Why i don't get expected result and how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's because `parcel-bundler` that the default sandbox uses to bundle the code

Comment: You could use the console of Google Chrome or any other web browser to get the expected result.